# How to efficiently label randomly rows in each group of a big dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a dataframe `df` containing 40 millions of rows. There is a column named `group_id` to specific the group identifier of a row. There is a total of 2000 groups.

[image]

I would like to label randomly elements in each group and add this information to a column `batch` of `df`. For example, if group 1 contains rows 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, then I choose a permutation of (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), for example, we take (5, 3, 4, 2, 1). Then I assign to a column `batch` of these rows the values [5, 3, 4, 2, 1].

I defined a function `func` and used parallelization `dummy.Pool`, but the speed is very slow. Could you suggest a faster way to do so?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import os
from multiprocessing import dummy
import itertools
core = os.cpu_count()
P = dummy.Pool(processes = core)

N = int(4e7)
M = int(2e3) + 1
col_1 = np.random.randint(1, M, N)
col_2 = np.random.uniform(low = 1, high = 5, size = N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'group_id': col_1, 'value': col_2})
df.sort_values(by = 'group_id', inplace = True)
df.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)

id_ = np.unique(df.group_id)

def func(i):
    idx = df.group_id == i
    m = sum(idx) # count the number of rows in each group
    r = list(range(1, m + 1, 1)) # create an enumeration
    random.shuffle(r) # create a permutation the enumeration
    return(r)
    
order_list = P.map(func, id_)
# merge the list containing permutations
order =  list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(order_list)) 

df['batch'] = order
```

Comment: If group 2 contains rows 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 - what is its batch? Is it just 1-5 again or 6-10 in someway

Comment: @JonClements in your example, the size of group 2 is also 5, so we create a permutation of (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) again. I mean the labelling is independent between groups. It only depends on the size of a group. All of this would allows me to control the size of the sub-dataset to use. For example, I can extract a subsample from the 40-million-row dataset by `idx = df.batch <= 100`.

Comment: If the goal is just to create a subsample of each group is there any reason for not just using [GroupBy sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) -> `df.groupby('group_id').sample(n=5)`? Which will both randomly select rows ensuring a specific amount per group and a permutation of the existing rows.

Comment: Do you actually want the permutations of the batches or just a number? And how is that going to differ from the group_id? I'm afraid I'm not quite seeing how what you're going to do is actually going to improve on anything else just add more complication?

Comment: @JonClements My ultimate goal is to sample `n` elements from each group and combine them together to form a sub-dataset. And I would like to test if the prediction is better if I increases `n`. With the column `batch` I mentioned, I can easily generate the `n`-sub-dataset by  `idx = df.batch <= n`.

Comment: Do you need the permutations for that... surely just the size of each batch would be fine?

Comment: @HenryEcker I'm sorry for my previous comment. Your command `df.groupby('group_id').sample(n=5)` is very fast.

Comment: @JonClements I don't understand your previous comment. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Does the batch column need to contain an actual list/sequence etc... of the permutations? As that's going to be awkward to use...

Comment: It seems from the existing code is just enumerating each group with values from 1 to n (where n is the length of the group) then the values are shuffled and assigned back randomly. Permutation sets do not appear to be stored. Each row just gets a random indicator. @JonClements

Comment: @JonClements I agree with Henry's previous comment.

Comment: Good to hear... I'll go get on and finish eating lunch then - looks like you've got people that grok your issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this could solve you problem.  Take a random permutation of the group size.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
l = np.repeat([x for x in range(2000)],20000)
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['group'])

df['batch'] = df.groupby('group')['group'].transform(lambda x: np.random.permutation(np.arange(x.size)))
```